# Where can I check my permissions as SQL Server user?

Tags: sql-server

Everytime I have to do a Restore from a backup, I have to log out from my personal user account from the SQL Server instanc and log back in using our main group user account, which I manage it too as currently no one else is using the sql server until the next DBA will be hired!
So  how can I compare our privilages and see the permissions allowed for this account so I can ask the IT department to grant me the same.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question.  Instead of wanting to mimic the permissions of another server principal, you should be granted the permissions and membership that you need to do in order to fulfill your job requirements (that goes for server logins that applications use as well).

So in other words, instead of copying the permissions from another login, just find out what permissions you need to do your task (sounds like a `RESTORE`).  Reference:  [RESTORE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the
>   database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information
>   is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role
>   membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and
>   undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed,
>   members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE
>   permissions.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply, I think I will have to read more about it to get better understanding as of right now I have no one to ask in the IT to grant me anything. So I was just curious as I consider myself a beginer in the SQL world.

Comment: No problem.  Your best bet is to look at the documentation on MSDN regarding what you're trying to do.  There will usually be a "permissions" section that'll tell you *exactly* what you need in order to accomplish that.